# update inner modal after all API calls from outer modal completes

Tags: angularjs

I am facing issue due to asynchronous API calls which are inside loop.

I have two modals open (one modal above other modal) and when I click button in top modal then it calls APIs in a loop and after all calls done I close top modal but bottom modal values should reflect.

The rows in bottom modal are reflecting twice because my broadcast is in loop.
If I put broadcast outside of loop then nothing gets updated.

For example (on button click of top modal):

```
app.controller('fileSaveSectionCtrl', function ($scope, $rootScope, $modalInstance) {
$scope.uploadFiles = function () {
   for(var i=0; i< selectedFiles.length;i++){
     uploadFiles.saveFile(payload).success(function(response) {
                // API call success
                $modalInstance.close();
                // this calls broadcast 2 times giving single row twice
                $rootScope.$broadcast('fileSaveUpdate');        
     }).error(function(data, status) {
                // some error                   
    });
   }       
 }
}
```

Bottom modal Controller:

```
app.controller('fileUpdateSectionCtrl', function ($scope, $rootScope) {
    /**
     * File Save view on file save should update
     * 
     */
    $scope.$on('fileSaveUpdate', function() {       
        updateFileSaveData();   
        $scope.filesGridOptions.data = filesArray;
        $scope.data = $scope.filesGridOptions.data;
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using promise as follows:

```
app.controller('fileSaveSectionCtrl', function ($q, $scope, $rootScope, $modalInstance) {
$scope.uploadFiles = function () {
   var promises =[];
   for(var i=0; i< selectedFiles.length;i++){
     promises.push(uploadFiles.saveFile(payload).success(function(response) {
                // API call success
                $modalInstance.close();
     }).error(function(data, status) {
                // some error                   
    }));
   }  
    $q.all(promises).then(function(){  
                $modalInstance.close();     
                $rootScope.$broadcast('fileSaveUpdate');
            });     
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use `$q.all()` to send the all request one shot and then after resolving all the response fire the event.

```
app.controller('fileSaveSectionCtrl', function($q, $scope, $rootScope, $modalInstance) {
            $scope.uploadFiles = function() {
                var promises = [];
                for (var i = 0; i < selectedFiles.length; i++) {
                    promises.push(uploadFiles.saveFile(payload))
                }
                $q.all(promises).then(function() {
                    $modalInstance.close();
                    $rootScope.$broadcast('fileSaveUpdate');
                });
                }
            }
```